# Load an html5 canvas into a PIL Image with Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, canvas, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get the contents of an html5 canvas and pass it to my django server, where it will then be manipulated with PIL and saved as a PNG. Here's what I have so far:

From the HTML form, the user clicks the "update" button, the canvas's contents 
- with canvas.toDataURL() - gets dumped into a text box that is submitted via a POST form. Eventually this will be automatic, but not for now.

```
<input type="text" id="canvasData" name="canvasData"/>
<input type='button' value="update" onclick='jscript:updateData();'>
<canvas id="sketch"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jscript:updateData() {
        $('#canvasData')[0].value = $('canvas')[0].toDataURL();
    }
</script>
```

The canvasData is in the form of 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...etc...=' when it gets sent over. Then I deal with it in django:

```
from PIL import Image
...
canvasData = request.POST.get('canvasData', '')
im = Image.somehowLoad(canvasData)
...
im.save('canvas.png')
```

And this is where i'm stuck. I can't figure out how to get the base64-encoded data url to load up the image into a usable form with PIL.

Thanks!

edit: here's the code for the bottom comment:

```
>>> d
'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K'
>>> d.strip('data:image/png;base64,')
'VBORw0K'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import re

datauri = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

imgstr = re.search(r'base64,(.*)', datauri).group(1)

output = open('output.png', 'wb')

output.write(imgstr.decode('base64'))

output.close()
```

or if you need to load it into PIL :

```
import cStringIO

tempimg = cStringIO.StringIO(imgstr.decode('base64'))

im = Image.open(tempimg)
```

Comment: I'm getting an Incorrect padding exception when I use .decode(). Should I be stripping out some of the 'data:image...' at the beginning of the string? I've tried different variations on that and it hasn't helped.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simple regex to get the base64 encoded data from the data URI.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with my solution just now; python is stripping out one extra character than i intended. (Any idea why this is?) Thanks a lot for your help, i'll go with your re version as i'll  have a lot less headaches than with this one:

    [Code moved to top post for formatting]

Comment: Oh, and the reason why stripping doesn't work is that it doesn't match  the complete string you give it as an argument, it matches any character in the string. Seeing as the string contains an `i`, it is removed from the beginning of the data.

Comment: Great answer! Is re.search(r'base64,(.*)', datauri).group(1) optimized or can it be more efficient? I would like to avoid the regexp engine to read the whole string whereas we only need to remove the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="width" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="height" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="image_data" value="">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```js
function submit_pixels(canvas) {
    $('form input[name=image_data]').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    $('form input[name=width]').val(canvas.width);
    $('form input[name=height]').val(canvas.height);
    $('form').submit();
}
```

Django POST Request View:

```py
# in the module scope
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import re
import base64

# in your view function
image_data = request.POST['image_data']
image_width = int(request.POST['width'])
image_height = int(request.POST['height'])
image_data = re.sub("^data:image/png;base64,", "", image_data)
image_data = base64.b64decode(image_data)
image_data = BytesIO(image_data)
im = Image.open(image_data)
assert (image_width, image_height,) == im.size
```

Bump up the maximum POST size in your settings (example: ~20 MB):

```py
# canvas data urls are large
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 20_000_000
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2019 with python3 i tried Acorn answer, and i got 
Error 'str' object has no attribute 'decode '
So i did some searching and adjusted the code and it worked here it is

```
from binascii import a2b_base64
import re

datauri = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

imgstr = re.search(r'base64,(.*)', datauri).group(1)

binary_data = a2b_base64(imgstr)

Out = open('image.png', 'wb')
Out.write(binary_data)
Out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Django 3.0 and python 3.7**
code in the html file (which are called templates in the django)

```html
<form method="POST" id="form1">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <canvas id="camera--sensor"></canvas>
        <!-- Camera view -->
        <video id="camera--view" autoplay playsinline></video>
        <!-- Camera output -->
        <img src="//:0" alt="" id="camera--output" onclick="show()"> 
        <!-- Camera trigger -->
        
        <input type="hidden" id="captured_image" name="captured_image">
        <input id="upload_image"  type="submit" onclick="save()" value="Upload the image">
    </form>
```

in the javascript file

```css
var canvas;
function save(){
            canvas = document.getElementById('camera--sensor');
            document.getElementById('captured_image').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          
        }
```

in the views.py file for Django

```
def capture_image(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        # print("-------",request.POST)
        if request.POST.get('captured_image'):
            captured_image = request.POST.get('captured_image')
            # imgstr = captured_image.decode('base64')
            imgstr = re.search('base64,(.*)', captured_image).group(1)
            imgstr = base64.b64decode(imgstr)
            # print(imgstr)
            tempimg = io.BytesIO(imgstr)

            im = Image.open(tempimg)
```