# Save and load image from client to server with django

Tags: django, encoding, client-server, todataurl

Here is how I send data from the client (coffeescript & dajaxice):

```
imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
Dajaxice.draw.saveImage( @saveImage_callback, {'image': imageData } )
```

Here is how I save my image on the server (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7774848/719276))

```
@dajaxice_register
def saveImage(request, image):

   imageData = re.search(r'base64,(.*)', image).group(1)
   output = open('image.png', 'wb')
   output.write(imageData.decode('base64'))
   output.close()
```

I would like to load the image and send it like so:

```
inputfile = open('image.png', 'rb')
imageData = inputfile.read().encode('base64')
inputfile.close()
return simplejson.dumps( { 'image': imageData } )
```

But this does not give me the exact same data, and my client fails to draw the returned image. imageData ends with `2OWn9u2` when I write it, and `2OWn` when I read it (missing '9u2').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the difference of data is not a problem, it works. Here is how I draw the returned image on my client:

```
saveImage_callback: (result)=>
    imageData = 'data:image/png;base64,'+result.image
    image = new Image()
    image.src = imageData
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 300, 300, 300, 300)
```