# Load an html5 canvas into a PIL Image with Django and save it in new File

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I test this example : question source : [Load an html5 canvas into a PIL Image with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774686/load-an-html5-canvas-into-a-pil-image-with-django)

```
import re

datauri =  'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg
AAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8  /w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgl
jNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

imgstr = re.search(r'base64,(.*)', datauri).group(1)

output = open('output.png', 'wb')

output.write(imgstr.decode('base64'))

output.close()
```

but I have an error on this line:

output.write(imgstr.decode('base64'))

here is the error: File "C:\django_projects\intranet\intranet\capture\views.py", line 19, in enregistre_image output.write(imgstr.decode('base64')) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

could you tell me what I'm doing wrong thank you Christophe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) (you probably searched for a solution in Python, and got a version that worked in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x)).

In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), a `str`ing has no `.decode(..)` method anymore. You can use the `base64` library:

```
from base64 import b64decode
output.write(b64decode(imgstr))
```

Comment: Thank you Willem, i'm in python 3.x, now it's works fine